# HDMI-out to VGA-in via DVI?

Tags: hdmi, vga, dvi

I have an HP ultrabook which does not have a VGA-out port. I would like to connect it to a VGA only projector
Will a hdmi to dvi converter like
http://www.ebay.in/itm/New-DVI-I-Dual-Link-female-to-HDMI-Male-Adapter-Converter-Coupler-24-5-pin-/261132860719 and then a DVI to VGA converter like
http://www.ebay.in/itm/29-Pin-24-5-DVI-Male-to-VGA-Female-Adapter-Converter-/161026086839? setup work ?

Or do I need something like http://www.ebay.in/itm/HDMI-to-VGA-Converter-Adapter-Cable-The-simplest-converter-/251095745415 ?

Comment: Standard `HDMI<->DVI-D` + `DVI-A<->VGA` won't work. But you should check whether your device is compatible with [this kind of adapter](http://www.shopping.hp.com/en_US/home-office/-/products/Accessories/Cables/NP031AA), your HDMI port *may* not only be a *standard* HDMI port.

Answer (score 4):

[HDMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hdmi) can easily be converted to **digital** DVI.

**Analog** DVI can easily be converted to analog VGA.

The step in the middle where you want to convert the digital DVI to analog [DVI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface) is not trivial and requires an active and relative expensive<sup>*</sup> adapter.

It might actually be cheaper to buy an USB graphical card with a VGA out and use that as a second display.

---

<sup>*</sup>Expensive as in the order of: £50 / US $76 / 4100Rp

Answer (score 2):

HDMI is digital-only. VGA is analog-only. You will need an active converter.

Comment: I thought only VGA to HDMI meeded a converter, but HDMI to VGA doesn't?

Comment: @tarashish Both require an active converter. It's possible that one might require an external power source, and the other might not, however.

Comment: It seems I'm doomed then.

Comment: Actually some non-standard HDMI sockets contain some pins for analog output, especially on mobile devices ([example](http://www.amazon.com/Micro-Adapter-Cable-TF201-TF300/dp/B006AR1QAA) for some Asus tablets). But this is completely manufacturer/device specific.